# .htaccess file is not redirecting HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https

I just purchased a UCC/SAN SSL certificate from GoDaddy and now I'm trying to get my website (mannyrothman.com) to automatically redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

This is the content of my ".htaccess" file:

```
## Go Daddy servers need the Options -MultiViews code below
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Hide .html extension
## External Redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\index.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,NC]

## ## Internal Redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}index.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}index.html
# Begin Muse Generated redirects
# End Muse Generated redirects
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

and if you want to redirect from https://ww.stackoverflow.com/ to https://stackoverflow.com/ use this too

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.rawertest.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```